# Jackson: Deserialize interface without annotations and mix-ins

Tags: interface, jackson

I am trying to create a way to serialize and deserialize objects to JSON using Jackson without having to rely on annotations, mix-ins or any code that is object-specific (ie: specific deserializers). However, I'm having trouble deserializing interfaces.

An idea that I had was to store the class name of the object within the JSON. For instance, if I have the following classes:

**MyClassOne.java**

```
package test.classes;

public class MyClassOne{

    private String myString;
    private MyClass myReference;

    public MyClassOne(String myString, MyClass myReference) {
        this.myString = myString;
        this.myReference = myReference;
    }
    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }
    public MyClass getMyReference() {
        return myReference;
    }
}
```

**MyClassTwo.java**

```
package test.classes;

public class MyClassTwo implements MyClass{

    private int myInt;

    public MyClassTwo(int myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }
    public int getMyInt() {
        return myInt;
    }
}
```

I would like to use Jackson to serialize `MyObjectOne` instances into something similar to:

```
{
"_class":"test.classes.MyClassOne" ,
"myString":"Hello World",
"myReference":{
    "_class":"test.classes.MyClassTwo", 
    "myInt":2
    }
}
```

I was wondering if that could work and how to accomplish it with Jackson.

Comment: I do not think this can be easy, you are going to implement some portion of Apache Avro(putting schema along with data) https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An idea that I had was to store the class name of the object within the JSON.

You could consider [`enableDefaultTypingAsProperty()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping,%20java.lang.String)) for automatic inclusion of type information:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, "_class");
```

---

> I am trying to create a way to serialize and deserialize objects to JSON using Jackson without having to rely on annotations, mix-ins or any code that is object-specific (ie: specific deserializers).

Consider the following code using the types defined in your own question:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, "_class");

MyClass myClass = new MyClassTwo(2);
MyClassOne myClassOne = new MyClassOne("Hello World", myClass);

String json = mapper.writer()
        .withDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(myClassOne);
```

It will produce the following JSON:

```js
{
  "_class" : "com.example.examples.foo.MyClassOne",
  "myString" : "Hello World",
  "myReference" : {
    "_class" : "com.example.examples.foo.MyClassTwo",
    "myInt" : 2
  }
}
```

To deserialize the above JSON, however, your classes must have a default constructor (or use [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html)).